# Turn Android Flashlight on with C++

Tags: java, android, c++, mobile

I'm trying to optimise flashlight strobe code within an Android app and have begun to try and write this part of the app in C++.

In Java I'm comfortable with the basic code to turn on the flashlight (using the latest Camera API):

```
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    String cameraId;
    try {
        cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, would someone be able to assist with how to turn the flashlight on with C++ code? I'm struggling to find any sort of documentation or any examples of how to do this (my attempts so far feel quite a way off and aren't probably worth sharing!).

Thank you

Comment: If there are no native C++ example, you could use JNI to call into the Java code.

Comment: Looks like it can be done from the docs (too much for me to read all of) search for "torch" in https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera